# Magento bulk purchase for cloth cutpiece and roll

Tags: magento-1.8

I am developing a fabric site using magento where I need to implement bulk purchase functionality same as on http://www.fabricuk.com/fabrics/106-nylon-dress-net.html but I have no idea how to proceed. So please help me to find out the way. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to look at tier pricing.

Following the example in the url, you set the price of the product to 1.99. This is your price for one unit (in this case 1 meter).

Then you add a tier price to the product with a quantity of 40 and price 1.65.

More information: http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/how-do-i-use-tier-pricing